# Spreadsheet to copy informations from another sheets - Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking way to create easier version of my code. I want to, copy information from every sheet to one sheet. First informations from first sheet, then below from second sheet etc. Now I have every each code for sheet, it is any way to make it easier? What code should use? Below my code and drawing with explanation.

```js
function copy() {
  
 var ur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // sheet where we copy data
 var urgents = ur.getSheetByName("List"); 
 var lastRow = urgents.getLastRow();
 var range = urgents.getRange("A2:B");
   range.clear(); // every time script clear data 

 var importsh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('115nqlMpW3dhI-adpWvir5RZeayM01HqvjOcDc2_yLvQ');
 
 var imbrak = importsh.getSheetByName('List_1'); // sheet from  we copy data
 var imbrak2 = importsh.getSheetByName('List_2'); // sheet from we copy data
 var lastcol = importsh.getLastColumn();
 var lastcol2 = imbrak2.getLastColumn();

 var last = imbrak.getLastRow();
 var last2 = imbrak2.getLastRow();

 var urlast = last;
 var urlast2 = last2;

    
var data = imbrak.getRange("A2:B"+last).getValues();
var data2 = imbrak2.getRange("A2:B"+last2).getValues();

  urgents.getRange("A2:B"+last).setValues(data);
  urgents.getRange(getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow3(),1,last2-1,2).setValues(data2);
               
 }
```

[image]

Regards

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your help. I have only one question, what should I change in code if I have more than one Spreadsheet?

Comment: When you want to retrieve values from several spreadsheet, please prepare an array for file IDs like my current answer. And then you can retrieve them by giving the file IDs to ``SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)`` using for loop. At that time, please also check the array for the sheet names. If this was not useful, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as one of several answers.

#### Modification points :

- Use an array for sheet names.

  - By this, when it increases the number of sheets, you can use this script by importing the sheet names to the array.
- All data of each sheets is imported to an array.

  - By this, the data can be imported to the destination sheet by one call of `setValues()`.

#### Modified script :

```
function copy() {
  var ur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // sheet where we copy data
  var urgents = ur.getSheetByName("List"); 
  var lastRow = urgents.getLastRow();
  var range = urgents.getRange("A2:B");
  range.clear(); // every time script clear data

  // Added
  var importsh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('115nqlMpW3dhI-adpWvir5RZeayM01HqvjOcDc2_yLvQ');
  var sheets = ['List_1', 'List_2']; // Please import sheet names here.
  var data = [];
  sheets.forEach(function(e){
    var s = importsh.getSheetByName(e);
    var values = s.getRange("A2:B"+s.getLastRow()).getValues();
    Array.prototype.push.apply(data, values);
  });
  urgents.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); // Please confirm this range.
}
```

#### Note :

- Please confirm the range of `urgents.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);`. Because I have no information about `getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow3()`.

  - In the current range, the data is imported to "A2:B".

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.